# Need to know the wifi access Point name in android

Tags: android

I need to know the wifi accesspoint name which the device is using..
How to do it?

Comment: You can take a look at the android.net.wifi package http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/package-summary.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html).

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     if (wifiManager != null) {
         WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
         if (info != null) {
            String ssid = info.getSSID();
            ...
     }           
}
```

Then you need to add a permission to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

An SSID/BSSID is not an access point name.

On a large enterprise network it is possible to have and SSID used across multiple physical access points.